# Configurable Product redirect

Tags: configurable-product

I'm looking for a extension that helps me to achieve this type of function in to my configurable products. Anyone?

We need the product information changes (Name, SKU, Price, Description and Additional information). Pretty much the page to be redirected once an option is selected on a dropdown menu. Please see example

Example
http://shop.mdminc.com/c/sequence-pumps_sequence-750

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Fire Bear Studio has a module that does such: https://firebearstudio.com/improved-configurable-product.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a commercial extension, which seems to  fit your needs:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/improved-configurable-product.html

And this is a free one: https://bitbucket.org/modulprogrammierer/dmp_betterconfigurableproducts
which works quite well for the most part, but some of the code is a little too old and doesn't play well non-XHTML markup (the attribute preselection via "s" parameter in the URL functionality). So you'd have to fix that yourself or comment that part of the code out  (which is what I have done in one of my stores), depending on your template.

Another free extension is called "Simple configurable products", but that one only updates the price... you could modify it to update the other attributes, too.

The first extension would probably be your best bet though.